# Remove hidden attribute from tr tag

Tags: javascript, hidden, tr

I am relatively new to coding and I am trying to remove the "hidden" attribute from a `tr` tag if I press a button. I tried this by using `removeAttribute` but nothing happens. I tried this with other tags like `button` to see if the problem is related with the actual `tr` tag but nothing worked.
This is the html:

```html
<tr class="hidden1"> <!-- hidden -->
    <td><img src="/Users/benrodgers/Desktop/Coding/Project/greenArrowUp.png" id="redDown"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <textarea name="userimp" id="userImp" disabled></textarea>
        <button type="button" id="editBTN" onclick="edit()">:</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This the JS:

```js
function addComment() {
    var addCom = prompt("Add you comment if you have any tips");
    if (addCom != null) {
        document.myForm.userinp.value = addCom;
        document.getElementsByClassName("hidden1").removeAttribute('hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements

Comment: use as `getElementsByClassName("hidden1")[0]`

Comment: It would be helpful to share more of your HTML template. Why? Because you might write a generic function that can be called based on the contents of a section e.g. having a `tr` visible when clicking on a `button` from the same section where both elements are contained.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** You need to select the first element from the ClassName, since `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection (kind of array but not exactly) . Also, you need to remove the attribute name which is `class` not the value :)

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hidden1")[0].removeAttribute("class");
```

**Method 2:** You can also remove this class using the below method:

```
document.querySelector(".hidden1").classList.remove("hidden1")
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be work for you:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("hidden1")[0].classList.remove("hidden1");
```

because getElementsByClassName returns an collection. in this case index 0 be worked.

**Note!**

but if you have more tr tags in your table the you have to implement an uniqu selector. or dynamic class names.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that there is no `"hidden"` attribute on the `<tr>` which you can remove.
I guess you wanted to remove the `"hidden1"` class from the `<tr>`.
In this case you can do the following:

```
function addComment()
    {
    var addCom = prompt("Add you comment if you have any tips");
    if (addCom != null)
        {
        document.myForm.userinp.value = addCom;
        document.getElementsByClassName("hidden1")[0].classList.remove("hidden1");
        }
}
```

Notice that the `document.getElementsByClassName` returns with an Array (actually a collection, but it's like Array), so you have to refer to it's member to refer to an actual DOM element.